# System.Printing skips a few job status states?

Tags: .net, system.printing, print-spooler-api

I am sending print jobs to the printer and I try to keep track of their status in order to reflect it in a queue of my own.

It seems as if the print jobs never go through "Printed", "Completed" status.

I made a small test program to see if maybe I was using the .net object the wrong way but this still happened. I ran my test program to query for a new print job and once there was a one I heavily polled it and refreshed every time to see its status and make sure I don't miss anything.

```
PrintServer ps = new PrintServer(@"\\printServer");
PrintQueue pq = new PrintQueue(ps, "PDF Writer - bioPDF");
PrintSystemJobInfo jobInfo = null;

while (jobInfo == null)
{
    pq.Refresh();
    var printJobs = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection(); 

    foreach (var printJob in printJobs)
    {
        printJob.Refresh();

        jobInfo = printJob;
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

PrintJobStatus jobStatus = PrintJobStatus.None;
PrintJobStatus prevJobStatus = PrintJobStatus.None;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        jobInfo.Refresh();
    } catch { }

    prevJobStatus = jobStatus;
    jobStatus = jobInfo.JobStatus;

    if (jobStatus != prevJobStatus)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**UPDATE**");
        SpotTroubleUsingProperties(jobInfo); // Microsoft example method that prints a description of each possible job status
    }

    Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

The result I get, even though the document is printed, is:

```
**UPDATE**
The job is spooling now.
**UPDATE**
The job is printing now.
**UPDATE**
The user or someone with administration rights to the queue has deleted the job. It must be resubmitted.
```

How can I know when the document is in "Completed" status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you enable the "Keep printed documents" option for the printer, you're never going to see the `Completed` status since print jobs are deleted as soon as they finish.  The transition is `Printing-->Deleting,` not `Printing-->Completed-->Deleting`.

So you have two possible signals that a job has completed:  1) When it enters the `Deleting` status and 2) when it vanishes from the queue.  To my knowledge, there is no way to distinguish between a print job being deleted because it completed and because a person or other program deleted it.

Comment: I was unaware of that option. I thought the ```PrintQueue``` object maintains that data for me somehow but now I understand it better - since it only samples the actual spool again when I call ```Refresh()```.

After changing that option you mention (too bad it can't be done programmatically), for some reason, when the jobs are done they are only in ```Printed``` status. ```KeepPrintedJobs``` is true for the ```PrintQueue``` object but ```IsRetained``` is false for the ```PrintSystemJobInfo``` object.

Also, jobs are at ```Printed``` status and not ```Completed```. Why is that?

Comment: @shwartz  I don't know why.  The entire printing subsystem of Windows is a bizarre, overly complex world that evolved from DOS and Windows 3.x, and it still carries a lot baggage from that era.  But if you need the keep-printed-documents option, it can be set programmatically.  Take a look at SetPrinter(), the PRINTER_INFO_2 struct, and the PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_KEEPPRINTEDJOBS option.

Comment: No, sorry.  Microsoft didn't bother finishing most of the Win32 API in managed code.

Comment: Well, you can still call all of the Win32 API from managed code.

Comment: Yes, but we're trying to avoid that where possible. We've had some issues with Win32 API code in the past.

In this case, I think it would be acceptable for us to set this up manually since I can make my code rather resilient to the case where ```KeepPrintedJobs``` == false.

Comment: In case someone's interested in setting this programmaticaly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110010/setting-printers-keepprinteddocuments-property-in-net

Answer (score 1):

I was just testing a similar situation and came to following logging output, **without** the 'Keep printed documents' flag set:

```
Info: 11/24/2017 12:08:18 PM - JobStatus for document testA4.pdf is Printing, Retained.
Info: 11/24/2017 12:08:22 PM - JobStatus for document testA4.pdf changed from Printing, Retained to Retained.
Info: 11/24/2017 12:08:22 PM - JobStatus for document testA4.pdf changed from Retained to Completed, Retained.
Info: 11/24/2017 12:08:22 PM - Document testA4.pdf marked as Completed by printer.
Info: 11/24/2017 12:08:33 PM - JobStatus for document testA4.pdf changed from Completed, Retained to Deleted.
```

Seems that it may be printer/driver dependent.

Code used to get this output:

```
public void MonitorPrintJobStatus(string printerName, Document document, CancellationToken token)
{
    using (var printServer = new LocalPrintServer())
    {
        using (var printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName))
        {
            foreach (var printJobInfo in printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
            {
                if (printJobInfo.Name == document.DocumentToBePrinted.Path)
                {
                    bool printed = false;
                    var previousPrintJobStatus = printJobInfo.JobStatus;
                    _logger.LogInfo($"{DateTime.Now} - JobStatus for document {document.DocumentToBePrinted.Path} is {previousPrintJobStatus}.");
                    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && !printed)
                    {
                        printJobInfo.Refresh();
                        if (previousPrintJobStatus != printJobInfo.JobStatus)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInfo($"{DateTime.Now} - JobStatus for document {document.DocumentToBePrinted.Path} changed from {previousPrintJobStatus} to {printJobInfo.JobStatus}.");
                            previousPrintJobStatus = printJobInfo.JobStatus;
                        }
                        if (printJobInfo.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInfo($"{DateTime.Now} - Document {document.DocumentToBePrinted.Path} marked as Completed by printer.");
                            document.Status = DocumentPrintStatus.Printed;
                            printed = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the transition from completed to deleting is so fast that only a polling loop like you did would ever see it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, if you look at the logs you’ll see that it takes about 11 seconds to get to ‘deleted’ 